# Is it stylistically wrong to use only "I'm" and "It's" in their contracted forms in a text in which there are no other contracted forms?

Tags: style, contractions

I have written a number of texts. They are not formal texts, but are aimed for language learners. In all of these texts, I have used "I'm" and "It's" while all the other forms such as "We are", "They are" and "You are" are uncontracted.

I was wondering whether such an inconsistency is noticeable and whether it would be justifiable by saying that "I'm" and "It's" are so basic and simple that writing them as "It is" and "I am" only makes the text harder to read.

My other reason is that generally speaking, the forms "I'm" and "It's" are used significantly more in conversations, because much of the time, we're talking about ourselves.

A sentence like:

> I am writing a letter.

Looks unnecessairly awkward to me and is more difficult to read  in comparison with:

> They are writing a letter.

An example of such a text is as follows, in which only "They are" is uncontracted.

> I'm a teacher. I'm in the classroom. The students are listening to me. They are very good students.

Comment: Contractions in this case are a stylistic choice. You can use them wherever you want and use the full version wherever you want as well. Nobody thinks about it that hard unless it's for formal writing.

Comment: **Contractions are more common in speech**. If you're writing dialogue it should reflect real life and above all sound natural. There's no reason why "*They're not doing any homework, they're on their mobiles playing games*." should look any less correct or more difficult to parse than its full form.